# Which is the best way to bring a file from a remote host to local host over an SSH session?

Tags: ssh

When connecting to remote hosts via ssh, I frequently want to bring a file on that system to the local system for viewing or processing.  Is there a way to copy the file over without (a) opening a new terminal/pausing the ssh session (b) authenticating again to either the local or remote hosts which works (c) even when one or both of the hosts is behind a NAT router?

The goal is to take advantage of as much of the current state as possible: that there is a connection between the two machines, that I'm authenticated on both, that I'm in the working directory of the file---so I don't have to open another terminal and copy and paste the remote host and path in, which is what I do now. The best solution also wouldn't require any setup before the session began, but if the setup was a one-time or able to be automated, than that's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but why can't you just use scp directly? With stored keys you don't have to enter any passwords either.

Comment: The problem with using scp is you need to type in the name/ipaddr of the local host, authenticate, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my preferred solution to this problem. Set up a reverse ssh tunnel upon creating the ssh session. This is made easy by two bash function: grabfrom() needs to be defined on the local host, while grab() should be defined on the remote host.  You can add any other ssh variables you use (e.g. -X or -Y) as you see fit.

```
function grabfrom() { ssh -R 2202:127.0.0.1:22 ${@}; };
function grab() { scp -P 2202 $@ localuser@127.0.0.1:~; };
```

Usage:

```
localhost% grabfrom remoteuser@remotehost
password: <remote password goes here>
remotehost% grab somefile1 somefile2 *.txt
password: <local password goes here>
```

Positives:

- It works without special software on either host beyond OpenSSH
- It works when local host is behind a NAT router
- It can be implemented as a pair of two one-line bash function

Negatives:

- It uses a fixed port number so:

  - won't work with multiple connections to remote host
  - might conflict with a process using that port on the remote host
- It requires localhost accept ssh connections
- It requires a special command on initiation the session
- It doesn't implicitly handle authentication to the localhost
- It doesn't allow one to specify the destination directory on localhost
- If you grab from multiple localhosts to the same remote host, ssh won't like the keys changing

Future work:
This is still pretty kludgy. Obviously, it would be possible to handle the authentication issue by setting up ssh keys appropriately and it's even easier to allow the specification of a remote directory by adding a parameter to grab()

More difficult is addressing the other negatives. It would be nice to pick a dynamic port but as far as I can tell there is no elegant way to pass that port to the shell on the remote host; As best as I can tell, OpenSSH doesn't allow you to set arbitrary environment variables on the remote host and bash can't take environment variables from a command line argument.  Even if you could pick a dynamic port, there is no way to ensure it isn't used on the remote host without connecting first.

Answer (score 9):

[zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/) (a [ZMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) wrapper over openssh) does exactly what you want.

- Install [zssh](http://zssh.sourceforge.net/) and use it instead of openssh (which I assume that you normally use)
- You'll have to have the [lrzsz](http://www.ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html) package installed on both systems.

Then, to transfer a file `zyxel.png` from remote to local host:

```
antti@local:~$ zssh remote
Press ^@ (C-Space) to enter file transfer mode, then ? for help
...
antti@remote:~$ sz zyxel.png
**B00000000000000
^@
zssh > rz
Receiving: zyxel.png
Bytes received:  104036/ 104036   BPS:16059729

Transfer complete
antti@remote:~$
```

Uploading goes similarly, except that you just switch [rz(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rz) and [sz(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sz).

Putty users can try [Le Putty](http://leputty.sourceforge.net/), which has similar functionality.

Comment: This is a great solution because even though it requires having an extra package (zssh) installed it addresses one of the points that other answers do not: this can make use of the current working directory of an interactive session. I would recommend this as an excellent simple solution as an alternative to my more complicated answer. My own answer is worthwhile, though, because it helps you learn the more advanced features available in openssh that are useful for other things, and it also encourages learning to use netcat which is another valuable tool.

Answer (score 4):

On a linux box I use the ssh-agent and sshfs. You need to setup the sshd to accept connections with key pairs. Then you use ssh-add to add you key to the ssh-agent so you don't have type your password everytime. Be sure to use -t seconds, so the key doesn't stay loaded forever. 
ssh-add -t 3600 /home/user/.ssh/ssh_dsa

After that, 
sshfs hostname:/ /PathToMountTo/ 
will mount the server file system on your machine so you have access to it.

Personally, I wrote a small bash script that add my key and mount the servers I use the most, so when I start to work I just have to launch the script and type my passphrase.

Answer (score 3):

Using some little known and rarely used features of the openssh
implementation you can accomplish precisely what you want!

- takes advantage of the current state
- can use the working directory where you are
- does not require any tunneling setup before the session begins
- does not require opening a separate terminal or connection
- can be used as a one-time deal in an interactive session or can be used as part of an automated session

You should only type what is at each of the `local>`, `remote>`, and
`ssh>` prompts in the examples below.

```
local> ssh username@remote
remote> ~C
ssh> -L6666:localhost:6666
remote> nc -l 6666 < /etc/passwd
remote> ~^Z
[suspend ssh]
[1]+  Stopped                 ssh username@remote
local> (sleep 1; nc localhost 6666 > /tmp/file) & fg
[2] 17357
ssh username@remote
remote> exit
[2]-  Done                    ( sleep 1; nc localhost 6666 > /tmp/file )
local> cat /tmp/file
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
...
```

Or, more often you want to go the other direction, for example if you
want to do something like transfer your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file from
your local machine to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the remote
machine.

```
local> ssh username@remote
remote> ~C
ssh> -R5555:localhost:5555
remote> ~^Z
[suspend ssh]
[1]+  Stopped                 ssh username@remote
local> nc -l 5555 < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub &
[2] 26607
local> fg
ssh username@remote
remote> nc localhost 5555 >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
remote> cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2ZQQQQBIwAAAQEAsgaVp8mnWVvpGKhfgwHTuOObyfYSe8iFvksH6BGWfMgy8poM2+5sTL6FHI7k0MXmfd7p4rzOL2R4q9yjG+Hl2PShjkjAVb32Ss5ZZ3BxHpk30+0HackAHVqPEJERvZvqC3W2s4aKU7ae4WaG1OqZHI1dGiJPJ1IgFF5bWbQl8CP9kZNAHg0NJZUCnJ73udZRYEWm5MEdTIz0+Q5tClzxvXtV4lZBo36Jo4vijKVEJ06MZu+e2WnCOqsfdayY7laiT0t/UsulLNJ1wT+Euejl+3Vft7N1/nWptJn3c4y83c4oHIrsLDTIiVvPjAj5JTkyH1EA2pIOxsKOjmg2Maz7Pw== username@local
```

A little bit of explanation is in order.

The first step is to open a `LocalForward`; if you don't already have
one established then you can use the `~C` escape character to open an
ssh command line which will give you the following commands:

```
remote> ~C
ssh> help
Commands:
      -L[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request local forward
      -R[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request remote forward
      -D[bind_address:]port                  Request dynamic forward
      -KR[bind_address:]port                 Cancel remote forward
```

In this example I establish a `LocalForward` on port 6666 of localhost
for both the client and the server; the port number can be any
arbitrary open port.

The `nc` command is from the `netcat` package; it is described as the
"TCP/IP swiss army knife"; it is a simple, yet very flexible and
useful program. Make it a standard part of your unix toolbelt.

At this point `nc` is listening on port 6666 and waiting for another
program to connect to that port so it can send the contents of
`/etc/passwd`.

Next we make use of another escape character `~^Z` which is `tilde`
followed by `control-Z`. This temporarily suspends the ssh process and
drops us back into our shell.

One back on the local system you can use `nc` to connect to the
forwarded port 6666. Note the lack of a `-l` in this case because that
option tells `nc` to listen on a port as if it were a server which is
not what we want; instead we want to just use `nc` as a client to
connect to the already listening `nc` on the remote side.

The rest of the magic around the `nc` command is required because if
you recall above I said that the `ssh` process was temporarily
suspended, so the `&` will put the whole `(sleep + nc)` expression
into the background and the `sleep` gives you enough time for ssh to
return to the foreground with `fg`.

In the second example the idea is basically the same except we set up
a tunnel going the other direction using `-R` instead of `-L` so that
we establish a `RemoteForward`. And then on the local side is where
you want to use the `-l` argument to `nc`.

The escape character by default is ~ but you can change that with:

```
 -e escape_char
         Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty (default: ‘~’).  The escape character is only recognized at the beginning of a line.  The escape character followed by a dot
         (‘.’) closes the connection; followed by control-Z suspends the connection; and followed by itself sends the escape character once.  Setting the character to “none” disables any
         escapes and makes the session fully transparent.
```

A full explanation of the commands available with the escape characters is available in the [ssh manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1#ESCAPE%20CHARACTERS)

```
ESCAPE CHARACTERS
     When a pseudo-terminal has been requested, ssh supports a number of functions through the use of an escape character.

     A single tilde character can be sent as ~~ or by following the tilde by a character other than those described below.  The escape character must always follow a newline to be interpreted
     as special.  The escape character can be changed in configuration files using the EscapeChar configuration directive or on the command line by the -e option.

     The supported escapes (assuming the default ‘~’) are:

     ~.      Disconnect.

     ~^Z     Background ssh.

     ~#      List forwarded connections.

     ~&      Background ssh at logout when waiting for forwarded connection / X11 sessions to terminate.

     ~?      Display a list of escape characters.

     ~B      Send a BREAK to the remote system (only useful for SSH protocol version 2 and if the peer supports it).

     ~C      Open command line.  Currently this allows the addition of port forwardings using the -L, -R and -D options (see above).  It also allows the cancellation of existing remote port-
             forwardings using -KR[bind_address:]port.  !command allows the user to execute a local command if the PermitLocalCommand option is enabled in ssh_config(5).  Basic help is avail‐
             able, using the -h option.

     ~R      Request rekeying of the connection (only useful for SSH protocol version 2 and if the peer supports it).
```

Comment: For a simpler solution to the problem, I recommend checking out the zssh answer <http://stackoverflow.com/a/49976/462302> however my answer is worthwhile for learning the more advanced features of ssh and making use of netcat which is an essential tool people should know how to use.

Answer (score 1):

Using ControlMaster (the -M switch) is the best solution, way simpler and easier than the rest of the answers here. It allows you to share a single connection among multiple sessions. Sounds like it does what the poster wants. You still have to type the scp or sftp command line though. Try it. I use it for all of my sshing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this I have my home router set up to forward port 22 back to my home machine (which is firewalled to only accept ssh connections from my work machine) and I also have an account set up with [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com) to provide Dynamic DNS that will resolve to my home IP automatically.

Then when I ssh into my work computer, the first thing I do is run a script that starts an ssh-agent (if your server doesn't do that automatically).  The script I run is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add < /dev/null && bash'
```

It asks for my ssh key passphrase so that I don't have to type it in every time.  You don't need that step if you use an ssh key without a passphrase.

For the rest of the session, sending files back to your home machine is as simple as

```
scp file_to_send.txt your.domain.name:~/
```

Comment: It would be nice if SCP / SFTP could be used across the already open SSH connection.  Too bad to do so would involve a protocol change.

Comment: But with public key authentication, there isn't any great downside to opening a new SSH connection.

Comment: This comment doesn't really address any of the points this person is asking which is to re-use the existing state without any extra setup ahead of time. Also SCP / SFTP can re-use an already open SSH connection using ControlMaster (-M) as some other people have pointed out. And there is a downside to opening a new SSH connection without ControlMaster which is it takes time to negotiate each new connection; on high-latency connections that can be quite noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [hack called ssh-xfer](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/ssh-xfer/) which addresses the exact problem, but requires patching OpenSSH, which is a nonstarter as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SCP protocol for tranfering a file.you can refer this link

http://tekheez.biz/scp-protocol-in-unix/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use this you can expose your files over HTTP and download it from another server, you can achieve this using `ZSSH` Python library,

**ZSSH** - ZIP over SSH (Simple Python script to exchange files between servers).

Install it using PIP.

```
python3 -m pip install zssh
```

Run this command from your remote server.

```
python3 -m zssh -as --path /desktop/path_to_expose
```

It will give you an URL to execute from another server.

In the local system or another server where you need to download those files and extract.

```
python3 -m zssh -ad --path /desktop/path_to_download --zip http://example.com/temp_file.zip
```

For more about this library: https://pypi.org/project/zssh/

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set up public & private keys so that no auth is needed.

Which way you do it depends on security requirements, etc (be aware that there are linux/unix ssh worms which will look at keys to find other hosts they can attack).

I do this all the time from behind both linksys and dlink routers. I think you may need to change a couple of settings but it's not a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

[Use the -M switch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896/which-is-the-best-way-to-bring-a-file-from-a-remote-host-to-local-host-over-an#49901)

> > "Places the ssh client into 'master' mode for connection shar-ing.  Multiple -M options places ssh into ``master'' mode with confirmation required before slave connections are accepted.  Refer to the description of ControlMaster in ssh_config(5) for details."

I don't quite see how that answers the OP's question - can you expand on this a bit, David?

Comment: This should probably be deleted and re-rendered as a comment. I am, however, with you: I don't get it.