# keep pipe chain over ssh open

Tags: c, bash, unix, ssh, pipe

I try to build a pipe chain over ssh.

`mkfifo localpipe;` and on a remote machine `mkfifo remotepipe;`

`cat localpipe | ssh -q einstein "cat > remotepipe"`

Using `echo "input;"  > localpipe` I can send input to a program that reads from remotepipe. But after that the remotepipe, the localpipe and the ssh-connection will be closed. 
Is there a way to keep localpipe and ssh open but to close remotepipe, which I need to in order to make the program on the remote side process its input?

If this doesn't work with cat or some other unix command, could I write a short cat replacement in C in order to achieve this?

localpipe may also be closed but I want to keep ssh open for speed reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open a connection which opens a `ControlMaster`, then multiplex your executions through the control socket it opens, as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515726/sender-and-receiver-to-transfer-files-over-ssh-on-request/519412#519412).

Comment: This seems to work! Is there a way to have a tunnel as ControlMaster? Also: can I add these options to my .ssh/config so that all ssh connections to a given host establish the connection in this way?

Answer (score 5):

The `echo ... > pipe` command closes the pipe after it is finished writing, which causes the `cat` reading from it to terminate and then the ssh connection to close as well.  Try opening the pipe with a file descriptor so that it stays open, like

```
exec 3>localpipe
# then ...
echo input\; >&3
```

The pipe should stay open until you close the file descriptor with `exec 3>&-`.

Comment: Thanks, not precisely what I need, however. Or maybe I don't understand correctly. I need that echo closes the remotepipe, because this tells the program at the remote side that it should stop reading from remotepipe and start interpreting. This should happen when I close with exec 3>&-, but this will close ssh as well, right. But I want ssh to stay open all the time waiting for me to send the next input. Maybe I can use a version of your commands on the remote side?